# Python Pychef: Not able to search attributes using class chef.Search

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I am trying to get list of nodes on my chef server that has a cookbook with specific name.

```
 nodes_list = Search('node', 'cookbooks:<cookbook_name')
 for row in nodes_list:
      print(row['ipaddress'])
```

It doesnt return any result. How can i search nodes with a specific cookbook name in it.

Comment: Could you please check my answer on your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61066017/remove-part-of-url-and-keep-the-rest-using-sed question once and let me know there if that helped you Shashank bhai

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a bash one-liner for loop :

```
for nodes in $(knife node list); do knife node show $nodes -r; done
```

If you want to see only nodes with specific cookbook :

```
for nodes in $(knife node list); do knife node show $nodes -r | grep COOKBOOK; done
```