# Remove part of url and keep the rest using sed

Tags: regex, sed

Need to remove some part of the url and keep the remaining part same .
Below is the part of my text file which contains like this

```
{
  host = "http://nxt-newepisode.xcfm.crata.dive.com/err1.2.2/table/kenny.xml.gz"

}

{
  host = "http://nxt-secondepisode.xcfm.crata.dive.com/err1.2.2/table/kenny.xml.gz"
}
```

from above two urls i want get rid off **nxt-** and keep the rest . I know using

```
sed -i 's/nxt-//g' FILE
```

can solve the issue but i want to be specific and only remove nxt- for first url and nxt- from second url without making changes to rest of file.

I am trying this

```
sed -i '/host/s#"http://nxt-newepisode.*"#" "#' FILE
```

Comment: someone here had given this answer sed -i -E 's~^(\s*host\s+=\s+"http://)nxt-((new|second)episode)~\1\2~' FILE. this worked . Need an explaintaion on that

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/host/ && ++count==1{sub(/nxt-/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Once you are happy with results then to save output into Input_file use following:

```
awk '/host/ && ++count==1{sub(/nxt-/,"")} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: Looking for a sed solution. IS it possible with sed ?